# Outlook is looking for a smart card

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

Dell computer with Windows 7 and Outlook 2003.  I recently added a smart card reader to my computer for the National Guard so that I can access some military sites that require a smart card to log in.  Now, every time Outlook attempts to download any mail from my civilian AT&T account (a pop e-mail server), I get a message asking me to "Insert a smart card".  I've traced it to the send/receive feature (specifically receiving e-mails) but can find no reason that Outlook should be looking for a smart card.

Comment: Did this start after you installed the ActivClient for the CAC?

Comment: Did Outlook add any other accounts by itself? Give it a look in Email Accounts section. Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

> Navigate to Services.msc and check the settings for the smartcard service (try   manual).

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-do-i-disable-the-insert-smart-card-dialog-that/d0800e92-ed5e-4b6f-b811-1f0e1d38572c

Comment: If I set the smartcard service to manual, the user won't be able to use the smartcard when they need to though.

Comment: It didn't work anyway, but a good though.

Comment: I am at a lost. I would have to have a smart card reader to play around with it.

Comment: No worries. Got it sorted for now!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling all the Outlook specific updates and hiding them. Not ideal, but it solved the problem.